# Django Template If does not work as expected

Tags: django, string, if-statement, counter

i'm trying to create a HTML drop-down with Django that shows the numbers 1 - 250 in the template and always selects the last selection after reloading the page. For this i use a variable "clea" to get the value with "request.GET.get('clea')" from the url in my "views.py" to pass it as context.

To select the value in the drop-dwon I have the following syntax:

```
        # Context: {"VIEW": {"clea": "140"}
        
        <label style="color: white;">Amount</label>
        <select class="browser-default" id="clea">

        {% for _ in ''|center:250 %}

        <script>console.log("{{ forloop.counter }}" == "{{ data.VIEW.clea }}")</script>

        {% if "{{ forloop.counter }}" == "{{ data.VIEW.clea }}" %}

          <script>console.log("Worked")</script>
          <option value={{ forloop.counter }} selected> {{ forloop.counter }} </option>

        {% else %}
        
          <option value={{ forloop.counter }}> {{ forloop.counter }} </option>
        
        {% endif %}
        
        {% endfor %}
        
        <script>console.log("Finished")</script>

      </select>
```

Everything works except the If Statement from Django Template!
In the log you can see that it always logs false, except if forloop.counter and data.VIEW.clea are equal, then its true, as expected. But it will never log "Worked", although it logs "true" in the line above.
Does anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect the `if` statement contains things that you did not intend.

This:

```
{% if "{{ forloop.counter }}" == "{{ data.VIEW.clea }}" %}
```

just compares two hard-coded strings: `"{{ forloop.counter }}"` and `"{{ data.VIEW.clea }}"`. And they are always different, so the clause is always false.

Try avoiding the quotes (see [example of a similar usage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2501772/3694363)):

```
{% if forloop.counter == data.VIEW.clea %}
```

Make sure `data.VIEW.clea` is an integer though.